# How can you work out the ID of a users MySite

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, moss

In a Sharepoint WebPart written in c# I need to find out either the ID of the current users MySite, or check if the current site is the users MySite.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have spent the afternoon working on this and have worked it out.

Add the following using statements after referencing Microsoft.Office.Server.dll and Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Server;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;
```

Then access the user profile by doing:

```
ServerContext sc = ServerContext.Current;
UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(sc);
UserProfile up = upm.GetUserProfile(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
```

Then you can get the Site Collection ID (SPSite.ID) of the MySite via:

```
upm.GetUserProfile(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).ID
```

Or the Site ID (SPWeb.ID) via:

```
upm.GetUserProfile(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).PersonalSite.RootWeb.ID
```

Obvious, well not really!

Comment: That is much better than my idea :)